# Help with local gauge transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I have to prove that the following Lagrangian is invariant under local gauge transformation ($\psi\to e^{-i\lambda(x)}\psi$ and $A_\mu\to A_\mu+\partial_\mu\lambda(x)$, where $\lambda$ is real): $$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\psi^*(\partial^\mu-iA^\mu)\psi.$$

We didn't cover how to do it. My understanding is that I can skip the part with EM tensors, since it's proven in a book (Carrol, Spacetime and Geometry) and can instead focus on the additional part. I have approached it by replacing the transformed parts and separating them - writing $$(\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\psi^*\to (\partial_\mu-i(A_\mu+\partial_\mu\lambda(x)))e^{i\lambda}\psi^*.$$

Analogous to this I wrote the expression for $\psi$. Is this correct?

Furthermore, how can I derive Noether current and equations of motion from it?

Comment: It's correct so far, now you have to put it together and show that $\lambda$ drops out and you arrive at the original Lagrangian. I don't know, if you are expected to derive the invariance for the EM field's kinetic term again or not, but you would go there in a similar way. It's not that long of a calculation and quite instructional, I'd advise to just do the calculation for the kinetic term as well. ;)

Comment: It’s not correct. Either you’re missing another $i$ or you have the parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: @Ghoster yeah my parentheses were wrong on here, thanks!

Comment: @Photon thanks!

Comment: @Ghoster: Right, missed that one, thanks! There is also another sign error in the original lagrangian, fixed it.

Comment: @Photon Hey what do you mean with there is a sign error? I copied it correctly from exercises. Is it wrong in the exercise as well?

Comment: Maybe parenthesis again? The complex conjugation should act on the $(\partial^\mu-iA^\mu)$ and not just the $\psi$ and thus flip the sign for the $i$.

Comment: @Photon I am afraid you lost me. We were given a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+(\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\psi^*(\partial^\mu+iA^\mu)\psi.$ But as far as I understand it, you need only change the sign at a conjugated part, which is $\psi^*$. Why did you make the change $(\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\to(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)$? I fail to see the need for CC to act on anything but $\psi^*$.

Comment: The Lagrangian in your comment is correct again. The signs in the parenthesis should be opposite, because one of them is flipped by the complex conjugation while the other one is not. In your initial question both signs were a minus, so I edited the left one to be a plus, of course you can also switch the right one instead.

Comment: @Photon Oh yes I see, I checked my first revision. It seems I made a typo. Thanks!

Comment: @displayname17: You're welcome! :)